# In java, is an object considered a variable?

Tags: java, class, variables

One source I am studying defines an array as "a collection of variables under one name, where the variables are accessed by index numbers."

But then I realized that you can have an array of objects (or an array of pointers to objects, at least).

This got me to wonder what a variable is defined as in java, as I did not consider an object to be a variable. Jenkov Tutorials cites a variable as being "a piece of memory that can contain a data value."

And since I believe an object fits this definition, is an object considered a variable?

Comment: No, an object is not a variable. I would say the quoted source is imprecise.

Comment: would it be more accurate to say an array is a collection of objects...?

Comment: An array is a mutable, fixed size, indexed collection of references to objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling an array a "collection of variables" is arguably stretching the definition already.  But an array is certainly a collection of references that can be made to point to different objects in memory, and each such reference can reasonably be called a variable.

Asking "is an object a variable" is a little weird in the first place.  In `Object o = new Object()`, `o` is clearly a variable, though remember it's a reference to an object in the heap, not the object itself.

Honestly, "variable" is a pretty flexible, ill-defined term -- is a field a variable?  The return result of a method?  It depends on who's talking and what fuzzy definition they're using today.

Comment: Why would you say a reference is a variable? I'd say it's as much a value as any primitive. To use your own example, does a method returning a  reference type return a "variable"? I don't think so.

Comment: I now understand that o is a variable, and it is also a pointer/reference, right?

Comment: @shmosel: `o` is a variable -- maybe not the reference stored in `o`, but `o` itself.  I agree that the return of a method is not a "variable" in the conventional sense, but again, I consider "variable" such a fuzzy term here as to be pretty useless.

Answer (score 1):

> is an object considered a variable?

No, these are two distinct things.
The first one (the object) is the value and the second one (the variable) is a way to reference an object, generally to use it (invoking a series of method on it for example).
For example when you write :

```
new Dog()
```

You instantiate a `Dog`. Nice. But suppose you want feed it if it is hungry.
 
You cannot if you have not a way to chain a series of method on this object.

By storing the reference of the `Dog` in a `dog` variable you can do it :

```
Dog dog = new Dog();
if (dog.isHungry()){
   dog.feed();
}
```

> Jenkov Tutorials cites a variable as being "a piece of memory that
>   can contain a data value."

It says the same thing.

But this :

> One source I am studying defines an array as "a collection of
>   variables under one name, where the variables are accessed by index
>   numbers."

is rather misleading.
An array is an object that has a state that contains, among other things, elements of the array.
The way which the elements are referenced in is a implementation detail of the Array class and I would not affirm that each element is stored in a specific variable.

Comment: Ok, I think I'm starting to understand it now, but if a variable is "a piece of memory that can contain a data value," is the data value simply the name of the reference/variable?

Comment: Not necessarily. The variable is is just a way to say : I will have a way to use an object. So I use a variable that "points"  on it. And then it is nice as I can use this variable to manipulate the object as it refers to.

Answer (score 0):

An object is created when you call the constructor with the reserved word `new`.

For example:

```
Object a = new Object();
```

`a` will be the variable of that new object created and will go to reserved memory for that object. You are instantiating that new variable and that variable is associated with that object.

Comment: But isn't a the pointer to the piece of memory containing the data value? Not the actual piece of memory itself?

Comment: ...I don't understand your first sentence or what it's asking.  Please rephrase.

Comment: ok, so, our object, which we have named "a," is a variable, right? Then is it also a reference?

Comment: **The reference values (often just references) are pointers to these objects, and a special null reference, which refers to no object.** from [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.1](Java Doc) What this means that my variable a is saving to a location in the memory,

Answer (score -1):

```
Hope might this will help you to understand it better...

class Bulb
    {
    private int w;
    public void setWattage(int e)
    {
    w=e;
    }
    public int getWattage()
    {
    return w;
    }
    }
    class Test
    {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
    Bulb b[];
    b=new Bulb[2];
    b[0]=new Bulb();
    b[1]=new Bulb();
    b[0].setWattage(60);
    b[1].setWattage(100);
    System.out.println(b[0].getWattage());
    }
    }
```

here b[0] and b[1] are reference variables who have the address of two Bulb objects